# unable to render an array of strings using th:each atrribute in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

pls I tried rendering an array of strings with thymeleaf and its showing blank. does any one know the reason for this? The code is shown below:

````
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    //public String[] greetings= new String[] {"Hi","Hello","Watsup"};
    
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String getHomePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg",new String[]{"Hi","Hello","Watsup"});
        //model.addAttribute("msg",new String[]{"Hi","Hello","Watsup"});
        return "home";
    }
    
    //<h1 th:text=${welcomeMessage}>*Hello Peeps!*</h1>
    
}```

the html(thymeleaf) is shown below:
    
    <h1 th:each="msg : ${greetings}" th:text=${msg}>Hello,homepage</h1>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the attribute on the model by the "msg" key. You need to access that instead of greetings.

```
<h1 th:each="message : ${msg}" th:text=${message}>Hello,homepage</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks Zack! How careless could I have been lolz